# What is the easiest way to transfer Oracle database from one PC to another?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, data-transfer

i want to transfer my oracle database to another PC. What is the easiest way to do it? Are there any GUI tools to do it?

Comment: Why are people voting to close this as "off-topic"?  I could understand "Belongs on SF" but "Off topic"????

Comment: The answers provided below seem reasonable. And 'yes', Oracle *should* build a GUI tool to simplify this chore, because as I see it, copying the database files (i.e. tablespace files, control files, redo logs, etc.) seems like a chore indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

APC's answer is the way to go for a logical transfer.  If you're asking because you just want a one-time transfer to another PC then:

- install the same version of Oracle on
  the second PC
- create the same directory structure
  for the database files on the second
  PC
- copy the database files (tablespace
  files, control files, redo logs) to
  the second PC  **(with the database shut down on PC #1!)**

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to transfer database structures (tables, packages, etc) together with data (or indeed without it) is to use the Oracle import/export utlities.  As you're using Oracle 11g you should employ [Data Pump](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/utilities/htdocs/data_pump_overview.html) for this.  (On 9i or earlier it would be the old EXP and IMP utlities).

Use Export (`expdp`) to make the dump file from your source PC.  Transfer it to your target PC and use Import (`impdp`) to load it.

At this point I would link to the documentation but the Oracle online docs are currently offline.  So here's a link to the Oracle Wiki page instead: [find out more](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Data+Pump+Export+%28expdp%29+and+Data+Pump+Import%28impdp%29).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a GUI, oracle Grid control can be used to clone a database from one computer to another.